# Need script to find error in sqlcmd script

Tags: windows, powershell

I have below command to take the backup of sql database in windows and now we need to set exception handling code in it to trigger an email alert if any errors

```
"sqlcmd -S $serverip -U $dbuser -P $dbpasswd -d $db -Q "BACKU DATABASE [$db] TO DISK='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\$db.$date.bak'" -b  >> output_test.log"
```

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: `BACKU` = typo? Else that might be your error right there.

Comment: Lets get that found in the error log and trigger an alert

Answer (score 1):

As you specify the `-b` option you should get an ERRORLEVEL returned as 1 though you may want to specify a value for '-V' too.

All you need to do is query ERRORLEVEL and determine if it is greater than 0. If it is the there has been an error.

It's been a long time since I did anything with ERRORLEVEL but as I recall

> errorlevel Number

Specifies a true condition only if the previous program run by Cmd.exe returned an exit code equal to or greater than Number.

So you need to check if it is 1 (or greater)

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO errorHandling
REMerrolevel == 0
:errorHandling
REM errorlevel is 1 or greater
```

Comment: can you please share total powershell code

Comment: I have never written a line of powershell in my life. If you want me to learn it for you please contact me to discuss my rate.